# ASP.NET Core MVC project and latest Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I am new to VS 2022 ASP.NET Core MVC, EF Core 6.0. With lots of struggle surveying, I reached a point of connecting to a database and creating a CURD page. The default styling is not pleasing. So a little more effort, I could find a Nuget command to Nuget package

```
Install-Package bootstrap
```

This command installed Bootstrap 5.2.1. But the cosmetics of the `html` did not change when the program was executed.

I have not made any changes to default files, that is `_Layout.cshtml` or `Program.cs`. There is no folder named `App_Start` or `App_Data`.

How do we install other such styling `bundle`and use them in ASP.NET Core MVC ?

I think I am missing some thing here. Didn't have patience for more search and study. So posting here with a hope of getting help.

Comment: `I have not made any changes `...go and look at how bootstrap is used (in the documentation). You have to include the relevant CSS file(s) into your HTML page - probably the layout page is best, if you want it to apply across the whole site - using a `<link` tag. Installing the nuget package simply puts the bootstrap CSS and JS files into your project. It's up to you to actually _use_ them - the package maintainer can't predict how you're going to do that.

Comment: Or yes in asp.net mvc you can do it via the bundles functionality in C#, that just makes MVC generate the `<link` tags dynamically. That can be useful in certain scenarios.

Comment: Not Helpful. Please be kind to explain with example.  The Bootstrap.5.2.1 files got budled and installed at folder paths `<ApplicationName>/css`  and `<ApplicationName>/js`. In `_Layout.cshtm` I have set the new path but there is no change. Infact browser console is showing errors of no finding the `.css` and `.js` files.

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you did in the layout file, and what the console errors are. With some specific information it will be easier to specify the correct resolution.

Comment: Understood the Point sir. Seems I need to Configure my `_Layout.cshtml` to make cosmetic changes.  There are no methods or wizards that could just download and make our page look like the samples. Thanks you

Comment: No there are not. You must include the CSS and JS files in your layout file, and then adapt your HTML to make use the bootstrap classes etc., to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems We can Alter/Modify the Basic Template by Editing the **Default Scaffold Templates** Files that comes with the `VS 2022` or `Entitity Framework` package. These files are generally located in a folder at location `%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates`.

Located a Good Link of **[`Microsoft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/asp-net-mvc-override-the-default-scaffold-templates)** which will help readers and programmers.

It is always better to Make a Backup of ***Original Files*** before altering them. Also, these files are `Read Only`. So a person needs to open the *Text Editor* in *Administrative Mode*